# Invalid command ‘Order’, perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration failed

Tags: linux, apache

When I try to start or restart my apache server, I get bellow message:

> Syntax error on line 162 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
> Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
> Action 'configtest' failed.
> The Apache error log may have more information.
> failed!

and I tried find this error on google and fix it:

> http://linuxindetails.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/invalid-command-order-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-not-included-in-the-server-configuration-failed/

I get error:

> Module authz_host does not exist!

So, some body help me to fix it?

Answer (score 89):

I just had the same problem while upgrading from openSUSE 13.2 to openSUSE Leap 42.1.

The problem is not a missing module in the apache2-configuration.

The problem is the upgrade from apache 2.2 to apache 2.4.
"Order" and "Allow" have to be rewritten as follows (example):

in 2.2:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

in 2.4:

```
Require all granted
```

You can find more options an examples here:
[Upgrading apache2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)

Comment: Please note there's [mod_access_compat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) available for situations where configuration upgrade is not possible.

Answer (score 29):

With Apache 2.4 please uncomment/add the following modules:

```
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

Comment: More suitable if you need your `.htaccess` to support both 2.2 and 2.4.  I used this method.

Answer (score 26):

On SUSE 12, authz_host was already enabled, so I needed to follow **willoller**'s comment and enable mod_access_compat:

```
a2enmod mod_access_compat
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I can't access some of my projects now after this. I get access denied, 403. I had to disable it again with `a2dismod mod_access_compat` and restart apache2 service. Please look at the answer from *TheFan1968*, it is working for me.

Answer (score 18):

You need to enable the `authz_host` module. [Here is the Apache documentation on that module.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html)

I'm not sure what Linux distribution you are using but here are some examples.

**Ubuntu:**

```
sudo a2enmod authz_host
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**RHEL:**

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

# Make sure this line is not commented:
...
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
...
```

Comment: With apache 2.4 you might also need `mod_access_compat`.

Comment: Thanks 'willoller' - the 'mod_access_compat' thing worked for me.

Comment: @Jhill, I have followed your steps and found error: sudo a2enmod authz_host. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Apache2.4 on **Gentoo** then make sure you enable the following `USE` flags that will build the `mod_authz_host` into `apache` binary:

- `apache2_modules_authz_host` : Group authorizations based on host (name or IP address)
- `apache2_modules_access_compat` : Group authorizations based on host (name or IP address). Available as a **compatibility module with previous versions**.

If you are compiling the Apache2.4 from source code then you can follow the same guidance by using the build-time configuration options ([complete list here](http://howtolamp.com/lamp/httpd/2.4/installing/httpd-configure-options/)).

Answer (score 0):

/OHS/OHS_DOMAIN/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/instances/ohs1/httpd.conf

ERROR:
 <AH00526: Syntax error on line 220 of /OHS/OHS_DOMAIN/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/instances/ohs1/httpd.conf:>
 <Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration>

SOLUTION:#05-11-2023
Enable or Add this Module on httpd.conf
LoadModule access_compat_module"${PRODUCT_HOME}/modules/mod_access_compat.so

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).